# Cassandra inconsistent/partial records inserted

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, gocql

I have a table where I have 4 columns A,B,C,D namely. I am using LWT for all create/update/delete operations in this table. A is my only primary key. 
My queries are somewhat like this:-

```
INSERT INTO xTable(A,B,D) Values ('123','','456') IF NOT EXISTS.
UPDATE INTO xTable SET B = '789' AND C = '' WHERE A = '123' IF EXISTS.
UPDATE INTO xTable SET B = '789' AND C = '456789' WHERE A = '123' IF EXISTS.
DELETE FROM xTable where A = '123' IF B = '789'.
```

At any point of time it is not possible that we have a value of C in the record but B is blank.
But when I read from this table,

`select * from xTable where A = '123';`

I get the correct values of A,C,D i.e '123','789','456' respectively but B is blank.
Also there are no errors received in the execution of any of the above queries.

What can be the possible reason of this inconsistent data??

Cassandra version 3.7. 
I am using golang's gocql driver for execution of the queries.

EDIT - 1

I am using QUORUM level consistency for all queries. Also this is an intermittent issue. It occurs rarely and is not reproducible easily

Comment: what consistency level are you using for the select?

Comment: Can you put select query output here. From above you deleted B record.